# The below written code is giving the following error: Should have got an 'p' component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Problem Statement:Create a web page with a paragraph, which has a link at the end.  If you click on the link, it slowly fades into(about 1.5 sec a #FF0000 (red)block over the text and with a #FFFF00 (yellow)text on the top.

My written HTML code is below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>jquery</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("[href]").click(function(){
 $("p").hide();
 $("#div1").fadeIn("slow","swing");
 $("#div1").fadeIn(15000,"swing");
 $("div").text("WELCOME GUYS!")
  });
  });
 </script>
 <style>
 p{
 width: 400px;
 height:  90px;
  }
 div{
 width: 550px;
 height: 65px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 36px;
 color: #FFFF00;
  }
 #div1{
 width:400px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:#FF0000
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>
  Machine learning is a type of artificial intelligence (AI) that provides 
  computers with the ability to learn without being explicitly programmed. 
  <a href="#">click!</a> </p>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My error which i have to rectify:-
Should have got an 'p' component
false
What should i try now??

Comment: This program is showing that error although 'p' tag is clearly defined.

Comment: Yep looks good to me. No idea why the program shows wrong. You should clarify the context.

Comment: it look good.
https://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/9gw74df9/

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message you are getting?

Comment: Also, why are you using an [old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282673/how-to-resolve-this-error-use-of-getpreventdefault-is-deprecated-use-default) of jQuery?

Comment: exact error:                                         
                     testWeb(jquerypackage.JQAssignment1Fade): 
                     Should have got an 'p' component
                     false

Comment: It is a boundation of using this version of Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. No errors whatsoever in the log. Fades In the `div1` . The only problem I see is that You have 2 separate fadeIn functions right after eachother and only the first one is being used.

Comment: testWeb(jquerypackage.JQAssignment1Fade):
Should have got an 'p' component
false

Comment: Here's a working codepen. https://codepen.io/mmsmsy/pen/wegYmy It was working just fine for me, but for the example I've updated the indenting, because it wasn't clear for me. I've also commented out the first fadeIn effect and "swing" parameters, so that the one with 15000 milliseconds would work. The last thing I've changed is the jQuery CDN to the newest version. Just copy the code from codepen and it should be working perfectly. If it's not then it must be something on Your computer I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you so much but I think there is a problem on the company's website only.